# Seeking block (sub-district) level boundaries for India?

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, india

I'm looking for block (sub-district) level shapefiles for India. The GADM database only has files for the 2300 Tehsils, whereas I'm looking for the about 5500 Census blocks (sub-districts) for any year possible.

Comment: You might find some help, or at least an answer, in [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58574/where-can-i-find-municipal-level-administrative-boundary-data-for-india) from last year.

Comment: Is your question different from the following: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/58574/8104?

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is recommended.