# Seeking India Block Boundaries?

Tags: shapefile, india, data

I know this has been asked before ([Where can I find block (sub-district) level boundaries for India?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102318/where-can-i-find-block-sub-district-level-boundaries-for-india)) and it seems it is still not possible to get better than district level data as a shapefile, but are there paid services (I am thinking mapmyindia and such) that provide such data?

Has anyone tried this and how accurate will be their data?

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. Please edit your thread title to a meaningful question which provides enough details for future readers who might come here with a similar problem looking for solutions.

Comment: Can you clarify what exact data you are looking for? Blocks don't exist throughout India. The Sub-districts throughout India have different names: They might be referred to as Tehesils, Taluks, Mandals, Blocks, and so on, depending on the state.

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is recommended.