# shapefile for mumbai area or section wise

Tags: qgis, shapefile, data, geojson, india

I am working on a project in which i need to plot data on **Mumbai city map section wise or area wise** but i am not able to get **Shapefile** for the same.

Can anyone please provide me the link where i can get this Shapefile? or guide me on creating one using **QGIS?**.I mentioned QGIS because i know a little about OGIS and hence it will save time.

Also i tried **certain links** which are **listed below** but i couldn't find what i need.

I mentioned shapefile because these are easy to manipulate, later i will convert it into geoJSON and work on it so if geoJSON files are there then it would also help. An **image** is also provided below.

**Note: only the important links are listed:**

1. http://monsoon.mcgm.gov.in:8080/RESTFulWS/WardMaps.html0
2. http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/
3. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datameet/ZVeyx7vT49g

[image: this is what i want]

Comment: You are asking for a shapefile in two ways: 1. "mumbai city area or section wise" and 2. "Mumbai city map section wise or area wise".  Are you perhaps after the city boundary and/or its suburb boundaries?  I am wondering if your question may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58574/finding-municipal-level-administrative-boundary-data-for-india

Comment: For Mumbai there are shapefiles extracted from Open Street Map data here: https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts/

Comment: For Mumbai there are obviously no administrative boundaries in the Openstreetmap's database! I peeped into the mapzen's mumbai_india.osm.pbf, which contains only sparse data which are of no value for this purpose. Also, if quering the administrative boundaries of Mumbai with the Overpass-API I get no result!

Comment: Do you need the municipal wards? Or something finer?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe something more finer.....even wards will do..so that i can edit it further

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) may contain the shapefiles you're after with some corresponding boundaries. Select **India** as your country and your subject, I chose **Administrative areas** and received 4 shapefiles of differing levels. Choose the "IND_adm3" layer to see all the Mumbai areas within the *Maharashtra district*.

**Note**: The shapefiles are outdated as Mumbai is still named as **"Greater Bombay"**.

[image: Mumbai]

[image: Mumbai attributes]

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is taluka level actually...i need more finer maps...

Comment: I'm going to have to check out this DIVA GIS. It seems like a useful data source.

Answer (score 3):

Municipal ward level maps can be found here: https://github.com/mickeykedia/India-Maps

Comment: I understand your concerns. It is just that this data seems hard to come by, so I wanted to make sure that other people looking for this, actually find the data. You can include the link as a comment if you think that's more in line with the requirements of the forum. As for citations. I have none, but these 'look' consistent with the ward map as listed in the image above and from my own knowledge as a resident.